# How to fetch DFP Clicks and Impressions data from Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, dfpclicks

I am working on Google Analytics to fetch following data from [query-explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/)

I want following data for current Month:

```
userID  = saved in dimension  ga:customVarValue2
Timestamp = I took dimension ga:dateHourMinute
url = I took ga:hostname and ga:pagePath
```

I want only two metrics related to [DFP](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=doubleclick_for_publishers&jump=ga_dfpimpressions) clicks and impressions

Since there are no any DFP dimensions,so I entered only impressions and clicks here and it shows me query error (Please see the screenshot)

[image]

Can Anybody please explain me how to get data related to DFP clicks and impressions here.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

DFP Reporting needs to be set up before you can query on it. There are certain requirements you have to meet in order to be able to make the reports.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6183304